# @ondblclick event in Blazor also fires 2 single click events

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Consider the following in Blazor WebAssembly:

```
<span @onclick="Click" @ondblclick="DoubleClick">Click Me!</span>

@code {

    private void Click()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Click");
    }

    private void DoubleClick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Double-click");
    }
}
```

If I double-click the element, what I'll see in the console is:

```
Click
Click
Double-click
```

Is there a way to receive the double-click event without it triggering 2 single click events? I want to use both events for different purposes and they are interfering with each other because of this.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because of how the `ondblclick` event works.
Quoting from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondblclick

> The dblclick event is raised when the user double clicks an element. It fires after two click events.

So what you are seeing is the way it works :\

So you might have to trigger the single-click action after a small delay, if no double-click event occurs within that time.

Comment: Fair enough, it shouldn't be a big deal to do that. I was hoping there might be some tag I could add that would do it for me!

Comment: Although I would be able to implement the suggestion with the delay, I wouldn't exaclty describe it as convenient. Did you implement it? With Timers and all? Or with a click register being checked in the dblclick? Just curious.