# How to detect a double click on a table row in MudBlazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mudblazor

I am using MudBlazor and I would like to detect a double click on a single table row and react to the event. However, there is no double click listed in the [API of the table.](https://mudblazor.com/api/table) The single click is easy to do with the `OnRowClick` callback (see also [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398257/make-a-line-of-a-mudblazor-table-clickable)). There is no equivalent for double clicks.

I tried using the Blazor event `ondblclick` with

```
<MudTd @ondblclick="OnOrderDbClicked">
    // ...
<MudTd/>
```

I have two issues with this:

1. I can catch the double click. But I cannot make it aware of the row that was clicked (for which I'd have a workaround).
2. Also I'd have to add to to each cell because the `<RowTemplate/>` element just won't accept it.

I only have a crutch for issue 1: Bind a variable `MyOrderVM MyItem` to the `SelectedItem` item parameter of the table and access the object in the method that is called by the double click (because [a double click also causes two single clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633196/ondblclick-event-in-blazor-also-fires-2-single-click-events) which select the item).

I haven't done a lot of testing but it seems this could work but isn't there a better solution? Or do I worry to much about side effects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have said, currently there is no out-of-the-box way like with OnRowClick for double click. However, feel free to create an [issue in the repo](https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor/issues).

As a workaround, you could use your method 1 with a little adaption to stop the propagation of the click event to the MudTable. I think this way is easier to understand than the detour over the `SelectedItem`

```
<MudTd>
  // the click is handled by the div and not bubbling up to the MudTd
  <div @onclick="@EmptyCallback" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" 
              @ondblclick="@( (x) => DoSomething(context))" >
     // ...
  </div>
<MudTd/>
```

Here is a [MudBlazor Playground](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QacbuLlJGtCAgQNT) to show it.

Disclaimer:

I'm a contributor to MudBlazor

Answer (score 9):

###### UPDATE:

For people finding this on their search, MudBlazor does have a indicator for double clicks now. 
It is not an explixit parameter, but rather part of the `OnRowClick` parameter.
In the `TableRowClickEventArgs` it providers, there is a property `MouseEventArgs` that has a property `Detail`. The documentation to this property state:

> A count of consecutive clicks that happened in a short amount of time, incremented by one.

So by checking this against 2 you can react to double clicks. I´ve used this in my own application and can confirm this works.

Comment: I'm surprise that this feature did not included in MudBlazor's example yet. Thanks for your update, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `EventCallback` `ondblclick` in `MudTd`. You can call that and pass a method with your desired parameter. See the sample code below.

```
<RowTemplate>
   <MudTd @ondblclick="@( (x) => DoubleClickEvent(context))">
      @context.SomeItem
   </MudTd>
</RowTemplate>
```

Create a method in the `@code` section, and name it as you named it in the Callback. See the sample code below.

```
private void DoubleClickEvent(ContextModel model)
{
   // Do something with the model.
}
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask, how is your solution different from the one @Just_the_benno has posted?

Comment: My approach is inspired by @Just the benno's answer. I found that with the other approach if I have more than one 'Td' then it creates a dead space between each 'Td'. Double-clicking there does not trigger the Func. When the callback is placed in the 'Td' (not in the div) it rectifies the dead space issue. Plus it's a little cleaner code (in my opinion).